# Graphic design training options

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

I am a newbie in graphic design although I am a bit familiar with Photoshop. I want to learn how to use InDesign, Corel Draw, Illustrator and other design tools and I need advice on which training options to go for. Would it be better to learn on  my own or to go for a training class which should be very expensive for me considering my budget?

Should I go for paid training or online tutorials and videos?

Answer (score 2):

[Lynda.com](http://Lynda.com) is probably the best option for you.
They have excellent courses on a very broad range of topics.
It starts at $19.99/month, so it isn't too expensive - as a real design course would be and you probably get the same experience.